# Можно ли выполнять математические действия с Math.pow() в Java?

Tags: java

Допустим есть формула((4/3)*Pi*R^3) с которым можно измерить объем сфер. Я хочу возвести R (Радиус) в 3-степень с помощью Math.pow(R,3). Это должно выглядит примерно вот так:

```
Value = (4/3)*Pi*Math.pow(R,3);
```

Comment: `Value = (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * Math.pow(R, 3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double R = 0;
        do {

            System.out.println("Enter radius of the sphere or 'quit' to exit:");

            boolean correct = false;
            while (!correct) {
                try {
                    String ins = in.next();
                    if(ins.equals("quit")) System.exit(0);
                    R = Double.parseDouble(ins);
                    correct = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! Please try again:");
                }
            }

            double volume = (4d / 3d) * Math.PI * Math.pow(R, 3);

            System.out.printf("Volume of the spere is: %,.3f \n", volume);

        } while(true);
    }
}
```

Программа для нахождения объёма сферы